# Real Life Retrofit use cases with FlatMap and SwitchMap using a Subject or RXRelay

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, flatmap, rx-binding

There are a lot of great posts and articles explaining `FlatMap` and `SwitchMap`, but
I am asking  here concrete *complex* real life with examples
 on how to use `FlatMap` and `SwitchMap` with `Retrofit` using a Subject or RXRelay, so to add a level of complexity and close the scope of my question. Please no marble diagrams, or documentation definitions.

Comment: "There are a lot of great posts and articles explaining `FlatMap` and `SwitchMap`" - I feel that any answers on here will probably just reiterate a lot of what you've already read about, especially as you've stated you know what they do - "SO and the blogs are full of these definitions, and example where there are some strings that get flattened. I understood that!".  With that in mind your question is very broad.

Comment: Absolutely, posts should not be to large in scope, is against SO politic. I edited again the text so that I am asking a specific question on how to use Retrofit with Subjects or RXRelay with the two operator mentioned. Just I am afraid won't get any response because looks as a complex example